# Proving Impolite numbers are of the form $2^k$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

The wiki page for polite numbers noted that the only impolite numbers are of the form $2^k$, $k\geq0$. Being the half-baked fool I typically am, I went out to prove that numbers of the form $2^k$ could not be polite, and that worked out quite fine. The problem is that I am unable to come up with a proof that concludes that it is *only* these powers of $2$ that are considered impolite. As I recall, Ramanujan did some phenomenal work with partitions of numbers, so I fear that might come into play in the proof and, as a result, hinder me to go further with my quest.

Can someone provide me assistance/info on how to prove this?

Comment: The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polite_number) you cite contains a proof of that assertion.  It appears a little further down from the statement, in the section with the heading "Construction of polite representations from odd divisors".

Answer (score 1):

Claim:
Any integer, n, not of the form $2^l$ can be represented as the sum of two or more consecutive integers.

Proof:
Now, n can be factorized as $2^l\cdot{m}$ where m is odd integer greater than 1.
Now,
$$\sum_{i=k}^{j} i = \dfrac{(j+k)\cdot(j-k+1)}{2} = 2^l\cdot{m} $$
$$\implies (j+k)\cdot (j-k+1) = 2^{l+1}\cdot{m}$$

But $(j+k)$ and $(j-k+1)$ are of opposite parity. If $2^l > m$,

$$(j+k) = 2^{l+1}, (j-k+1) = m$$
$$j = \frac{2^{l+1} + m - 1}{2}, k = \frac{2^{l+1} - m + 1}{2}$$,

else if $m > 2^l$,

$$(j-k+1) = 2^{l+1}, (j+k) = m$$
$$j = \frac{2^{l+1} + m - 1}{2}, k = \frac{-2^{l+1} + m + 1}{2}$$,

In both cases, we can choose positive integers $j, k$ such that $j>k$ and $n = \sum_{i=k}^{j} i$.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$